# Why button click does not work with iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

For testing purposes I´m playing a little bit with iframes.

At first I couldn´t understand, why I´m not able to get the value of an input text withhin an iframe.

After searching I´ve found out, that you can only access the document object of an iframe, if it is from the same domain, as the main site.

I´ve implemented a test, in which I´m able to acces a input text from iframe.

Here is the code for the main site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IFrame Test</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style type="text/css"> 
        iframe#own{
            float: left;
        }

        iframe#spiegel {
            float: right;
        }           
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function searchFrameInput() {
            var iframe = document.getElementById("own");
            alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("in").value);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>      
    <div>   
        <iframe id="own" src="test1.html" width="49%" height="1000"> 
            <p>IFrames not supported!</p>
        </iframe>

        <iframe id="spiegel" src="http://www.spiegel.de" width="49%" height="1000"> 
            <p>IFrames not supported!</p>
        </iframe>       
    </div>  

    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="searchFrameInput();">
    <div id="res"></div>
</body>
```

And Here the Code for the "iframe"-site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IFrame Test</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickEvent() {
            alert("clicked in iframe!");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>              
    <input type="text" id="in" value="Test">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="clickEvent();">

    <div id="d"></div>
</body>
```

The Problem is now, that if I click the button within the iframe, there should be an alert, but nothings happen.
I Think that I´m something missing...so please help.

Comment: Works fine for me what browser?

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason that the `onclick` handler doesn't run and fire the `alert`, whether you load `own.html` within an iframe or by itself.  Are you seeing anything in the browser developer console?

Comment: I´m using Internet Explorer 10...yes own.html is loaded in an iframe. In the main Page it is the first iframe with the Name test1.html.

Comment: You files works very well. But if you load the page, the IE ask you if you want allow Scripts etc. You see the question at the bottom of the IE. You must allow scripts an ActiveX. You may have a look at your security options too.

Comment: The problem is, that on the main page (first file) the onclick event triggers the function and the result is shown...but in the iframe it looks like, the javascript code isn´t working or isn´t being called at all.